# ZeroMQ doesn't work in Unity, but works as console application

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, zeromq

I try to connect my python process with Unity game through ZeroMQ. I have a python script `server.py` which sends a message through pair socket

```py
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.bind(f"tcp://*:5556")

socket.send(b"Server message to client")
print("Sent")
```

And I have a `MonoBehaviour` script attached to a GameObject within Unity, which looks like this:

```
public class AiManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        using (var server = new PairSocket())
        {
            server.Connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
            var msg = server.ReceiveFrameString();
            Debug.Log(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The game hangs on `ReceiveFrameString()` forever and crashes Unity. Also `server.py` hangs and doesn't send the message.

However I created an independent console application, with the exact same code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var server = new PairSocket())
        {
            server.Connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
            var msg = server.ReceiveFrameString();
            Console.WriteLine($"From Server: {msg}");
        }
    }
}
```

This application works perfectly.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you mean the method is blocking for longer than you expect, or that you didn't expect it to block at all?

Comment: the method is blocking forever (5+ minutes until I kill the process manually) while console app works immediately

Comment: Try sending the message before receiving.  When a connection is made the server doesn't normally send a message back.  You have to at least send a return before you get a response.

Comment: @jdweng It works! Sending from client to server before sending from server to client somehow fixes the problem. If you could explain why it works and why it's not needed in a console application in an answer I will be delighted to accept it

Comment: In general a huge difference to a console app is that in the console you don't care if the thread freezes for a while until there is response ... In Unity, a frame based app will also freeze your main thread and the entire Unity Editor until there is a response -> use a Thread or Task

Comment: There is no issue.  I said a server doesn't doesn't do anything when a connection is made.  The server is a slave and waits for a client to send a command.

Comment: @jdweng in server.py you can see I send a message though. Also, in that case console application shouldn't work either

Comment: You are dealing with a different kernel/operating system with different drivers.

Comment: 75% ofd the time it's a stupid firewall problem, and nothing to do with the issues mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after multiple hours of experimenting and browsing the internet I have fixed the problem.

First thing to do, thanks to @jdweng's comment is to first send a message from client to server.

> Server doesn't do anything when a connection is made. The server is a slave and waits for a client to send a command. [...] It behaves differently as console application, because you are dealing with a different kernel/operating system with different drivers.

Adding a `server.SendFrameEmpty();` to the client and `socket.recv()` to the server fixes the problem, but Unity still freezes.

I found [this answer](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/issues/631#issuecomment-324172535) saying:

> The key is to have `AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();` before you start and `NetMQConfig.Cleanup();` before you end.

Finally the whole working code looks like this

```
public class AiManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        using (var server = new PairSocket())
        {
            server.Connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
            server.SendFrameEmpty();
            var msg = server.ReceiveFrameString();
            Debug.Log(msg);
        }
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a total PITA ensuring that Unity (ie, the Unity app) simply has permission to talk locally.

I assume you're on PC, not Mac, examine carefully if Unity is allowed to make such network connections.

Windows firewall settings can be a total PITA for Unity.

Read various threads, https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-multiplayer-networking-lan-wont-connect-from-another-pc.470459/

One solution is, spin up a real remote server on AWS, and try that!  It's often easier than getting localhost to work.

One shitty problem is that quite simply, on some versions of Windows the stupid "OK" dialog which appears actually appears *behind* Unity, doh, can waste hours.